# Why does std::lcm() not work even though I changed the language standard in project settings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I want to use the c++17 lcm function, but it's still perceived as an error by the compiler even after switching the standard of the project. Maybe I'm just missing something but every single answer to this problem on the internet was to simply change this one setting which didn't help.

For example this program

```
#include<numeric>

int compute_lcm(int x1, int x2)
{
    return std::lcm(x1, x2);
}

int main()
{
    int a = compute_lcm(2, 3);
}
```

does not compile with an identifier not found error(Error C3861 'lcm': identifier not found). VS version is 2017 community.

Comment: Did you `#include <numeric>`? Post the error please (copy-paste _as text_ into the question please)

Comment: Yes I did. Added the error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Next idea: maybe it's the missing `std::`? Many people (sadly) are `using namespace std;`, did you do that? If not you need `std::lcm(x_loop, y_loop);`

Comment: Which VS2017 version do you have? It was added in 15.3.

Comment: Can you please post the entire code that you are compiling? You should be able to reduce it to just a few lines.

Comment: If I put "std::" it says "namespace "std" has no member "lcm"". I have the latest version, which I had updated today before this problem came up. I'm adding an easier function to the question which shows the same error for me.

Comment: You can use create your own "lcm" function by using (x_loop*y_loop)/(std::__gcd(x_loop, y_loop)) just in case the problem still persists.

Comment: Well of course I can write a computing function, but I want to know why are c++17 features unusable for me. std::gcd also doesn't work by the way.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't exist for me either, despite Microsoft's claims that it should.

Comment: I added an entire cpp file that's not compiling

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler does not set up support for C++17. You could select `Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++ ->All Options->C++ Language Standard` and choose `ISO C++17 Standard`.
[image]

Comment: After I set `C++17 standard`, the program runs normally. I think there may be something wrong in some places or settings. Could you provide me with more information. Also, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3861?view=vs-2019) about C3861.